# How to add images in vscode - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am trying to add images to an asset folder in VSCode, but I only get the option to type the image name. When I do and click on the newly created image, it says "an error has occurred." I presume this is because I am only typing the file name, not adding the actual image.

I added the full path to the yml file, but nothing loads in the app.

```
assets:
    - C:/Users/tt/Desktop/Flutter_projects/Practise/imaages/images/assets/android.png
```

Flutter code:

```
child: Image(
    image: AssetImage('assets/android.png')
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use relative path to indicate the folder(e.g.`myImages`) that hosts your image assets.
then

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - myImages/android.png
```

see flutter doc for more info:

[Adding assets and images](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)